# Why is my HTML table not showing properly?

Tags: html

I have been following the tutorial at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com) about HTML tables.
My goal is to use different `<td>` tags.

At their website, they used this:

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Person 1</th>
    <th>Person 2</th>
    <th>Person 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Their code showed

[image: this].

However, I tried this with PHP. It isn't working and it showed

[image: this].

Here's the code:

```php
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT local_name FROM storms";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo $row["local_name"] . "<br>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, I looked into the HTML XAMPP made from my PHP code, and I found this:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
    Malakas<br>01W<br>                        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Basyang<br><br>                        </td>
</tr>
```

Could it be possible that this might be the problem?

Comment: Well, your code isn't producing the same HTML structure…

Comment: well the loop is not correct place the td tag inside of the while loop

Comment: If you want to have the same HTML table, then you should output the same structure in your loop. Each loop iteration should be a new `<tr>` and each field a new `<td>`

Comment: Is it possible that the table looks as it looks because that's what the HTML expresses that you produce? — Yes.

Comment: I don't see how that php could even produce multiple rows let alone multiple cells

Comment: @mplungjan, the code you specified doesn't work. Instead of showing the right one, it showed [this](https://imgur.com/a/eCNKPes).

Comment: @tugas44500 see my answer. You need to add more cells to show more data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a 1 to 1 row to row and 1 to 1 cell to cell

```
<?php  
  $sql = "SELECT local_name FROM storms"; 
  $result = $conn->query($sql);                             
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["local_name"] ?></td>
        ....
      </tr>
  <? }
  } ?>
```